# What is the best way to edit variable columned table in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to add some data with variable count of rows and columns to the WPF form, edit it and get it back (for future save & load).

All I want to know is a what approach is best for that?

I have tried the `DataGrid` but it seems to be allowing me to edit cells only if I set the `ItemSource` property but I can't do that because I am adding columns at the run time without any class instances because each time the column count differs.

**For example**:

I need a `5x60` (5 columns and 60 rows) table. Then (in a say 5 minutes) I need a `9x30` (9 cols, 30 rows) table. Then another one. And all the time I need to have the `DataGrid` (or whatever) to be editable.

Comment: There is no clean way that I know of.   You can bind columns in code behind to dataCol[0],  dataCol[1] ... but it is still going to expect the same number of columns in each row.  You might be able to create for the max and then bind to an active to disable.  Only a comment.  I use this for column count at run time but each row has the same number of columns.

Comment: You should post examples of your data and how it needs to be displayed.  You can probably configure a DataGrid in code at runtime.  When a DataGrid is configured at design time in XAML, it usually assumes a particular data format.  If the expected format is actually random then you need to programmatically design your grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the only way is to create the `TextBox`-filled `UniformGrid`.